# Black and white film, with alien bugs that burn human hands

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this film in the mid 1990's, but I'm about 90% sure it was a black and white movie, so was likely from the 1950s or 60's.

The film was set in an American town that was sparsely populated. Either an alien invasion or a chemical/nuclear accident caused creatures that looked like woodlice or another [Isopod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopoda) type creatures, to be able to give off excessive heat.

The creatures were large, and would just about fit in a human hand.

When humans pickup the creatures they cause significant burns to the individuals hand. I don't think they burn through a person's hand, and only cause significant burns.

I also feel the following elements may be from the same film, but I don't know if I am confusing two films as one. If that turns out to be the case I will ask the following in a separate question.

I remember a young teen girl looking out of a window to a hill that had a bright light behind it (it turns out later an alien spaceship has crashed behind the hill). There is a pathway with a white fence that goes over the hill, with a single tree on the top of the hill.

The girl sees people from the town going over the hill. The next day the girl meets them around the town and they have changed and become distant and aloof. The viewer is meant to believe that the person has been replaced by an alien.

The girls father dislikes what's going on and says that no-one should go over the hill. One day the girl wakes up to find her father has become distant and aloof.

The viewer is meant to feel that the father has gone over the hill, even though he said he wouldn't.

Comment: The second part of your question makes me think of the original 1953 Invaders from Mars (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045917/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) and the 1983 remake (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl1q3lunJyo).

Comment: The fence leading over a hill with a bright light behind it, and adults going there and coming back changed is from the 1953 Invaders from Mars.  But that stars a young boy whose room looks over the hill not a young girl...And while it's been some time since I last watched it I don't remember an insect that burnt the hand.

Comment: The first part of your question reminds me of Bug (1975) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2ywd7jWzUc).  You may well be thinking of two different films.

Comment: @Alith Bug and both versions of Invaders from Mars were in color but if A. Steer rememb ersone or both of them he thinks they were black and white. So possibly he remembers the details poorly after almost 30 years.   Hunter Carson has hair a lot longer in 1986 than JImmy Hunt did in 1953, and so would be slightly more likely to be mistaken for a girl.  and ther were smaller roles for girls in both movies.

Answer (score 10):

The first part of your description sounds like the movie "Bug" from 1975. "Bug" concerns a species of insect that comes to the surface of the earth after a quake. The insects have little friction organs in their tails with which they can start fires. A scientist breeds some of the bugs for study, and discovers that they are ancient and, in a way, intelligent. This movie is based on the novel "The Hephaestus Plague" by Thomas Page.

Nothing from the second part of your question was in "Bug", so either my answer is not your movie, or you have combined two films in memory.

[image]
[image]

Movie trailer: